# Sharing socket.io to other modules gives empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, module, socket.io

I am trying to share `socket.io`'s socket object in different node.js modules although I fail and get empty object with

```
Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

My code :

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

var routes = require('./routes')
  , path = require('path')
  , rss = require('./routes/rss')

// ...

exports.io = io;
```

**routes/rss.js**

```
io = require(__dirname + '/../app');

console.log(io);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(
  console.log("Connection on socket.io on socket");
  // .. do stuff 
});
```

That's the output I get from this :

```
$ node app.js                                                                                                    
   info  - socket.io started
{}

/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/routes/rss.js:10
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/routes/rss.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/app.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Although I have tried and I can do the same with `socket.io` only in one (app.js) file

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

var routes = require('./routes')
  , path = require('path')
  , rss = require('./routes/rss')

// ...

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  logger.debug("Connection on socket.io on socket");
  socket.emit('news', {will: 'be recived'});
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since, in `app.js`, you have:

```
exports.io = io;
```

then you would need to use it like so:

```
var app = require('../app');
var io = app.io;
```

That is you say, you *attached* a property called `io` to the module, so when you require that module, you get an object that has the `io` property set.

You could also do

```
module.exports = io;
```

and then leave `rss.js` as you have it now.

---

All that said, if you're running `app.js` with Node, you'll much more commonly see the `io` object injected into other modules (instead of the other way around); for example:

**`app.js`**

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

var routes = require('./routes')
  , path = require('path')
  , rss = require('./routes/rss')

// ...

rss(io); // pass `io` into the `routes` module,
         // which we define later to be a function
         // that accepts a Socket.IO object
```

**`routes/rss.js`**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(
    console.log("Connection on socket.io on socket");
    // .. do stuff 
  });
}
```

Comment: Using this method I will sometimes get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined` while trying to use socketio object as global one : `var socketio; module.exports = function(io){ io.socket.on('connection', function(socket){  socketio = socket; });` and then use it somewhere in the code;

Comment: That sets a top-level variable named `socketio` that refers to the person who most recently connected to the app. If no one has connected, it will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

I pass the `io` object into the `connection` handler.

```
var socket = require('./routes/socket.js');

io.sockets.on('connection', function(sock){
    socket.stuff(sock, io);
});
```

./routes/socket.js should contain the following:

```
var socket = module.exports = {};

socket.stuff = function(sock, io){
    //handle all events here
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? what should be in the 'exporting file' , `socket.js` ?